# Trying to implement facets on object type using sunspot on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot-rails

My basic goal is to create a facet based on the returned object type, not any specific field of the various objects.
I have a search in my controller that returns multiple types of objects. It looks like this:

```
def search
  @raw_results = Sunspot.search ProductReview, Vendor, Product do |query|
    query.fulltext(params[:search])
    query.facet(:class)
    query.with(:class, params[:item_type]) if params[:item_type].present?
  end
  @returned_items = @raw_results.results
end
```

If I call this controller with **/search?search=note**, I get back the correct items and the correct list of facets.

I added the `query.with(:class, params[:item_type])` line and now if I call the link **/search?item_type=ProductReview&search=notes** I get the error:

*undefined method `name' for "ProductReview":String*

Is there a more straightforward way to create a facet on object type? If not, what am I doing wrongif?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing a like a good 1/2 nights sleep.  There may be a more elegant way but this worked well...

I added a new method (`class_name`) into every Model I wanted to index:

```
def class_name
  self.class.name
end
```

(Actually, I put this into a module called `SharedMethods` and included `SharedMethods` in each model.)

In each model's `searchable` block I added:

```
searchable do
  string :class_name
end
```

And then just referenced `:class_name` when setting up the facet. Worked!